# Can I reuse fence panels for a new fence?

Tags: fence

I’m looking for an affordable fence solution. I came across a posting of someone selling 108 feet of pressured treated wood panels with lattice that were previously used as  pool fencing. Is it possible to use these panels as a wooden fence for my yard? The purpose of the fence is to keep my dogs secured.

If so, I’d look into hiring someone to dig and set up the posts, and everything else required, but would this at all be a viable option? Also the yard has a slight downward slope, does that affect viability?

I’ve attached photos of the wooden fence panels.

[image: fence photo]

[image: fence panel photos]

Comment: Labour cost can be much more than material cost.  Used prices are also much lower than new.  Look around at different fencing styles

Comment: If you look around the internet, you'll find pictures of stepped fences. Each panel remains level, stepping down at each post to match a slope. For pets I imagine that could be a problem, but not an insurmountable one.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site. Note that you've now posted under two different accounts, so be sure to use the one you posted your question with.

Comment: The slopes, as mentioned can be stepped *somewhat*—it depends on the slope.  You'd probably need to install some filler wedges so the dogs don't escape.  Your posts would obviously need to be slightly taller than expected on the downhill side of each panel.

Answer (score 1):

If they were a fence before they can be fence again. Note that the panels are obviously a fixed size, so posts will need to be set individually to fit their lengths. Other than that it's fairly straight-forward.